# Remove redaction block margin on revisions page

Tags: feature-request, design, moderator-tools, revision-redaction

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1002321/revisions

Strange padding:

[image]

Because of this rule:

```
.revision-page .redaction-indicator {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Could you remove this margin to make it looks like this?

[image]